# how to get information of google play store in my android application?

Tags: android, google-play-services

Is there any API for Google play store for getting application name, description, icon, downloads, ratting ??

I found [this one](https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/) but its an Ruby language code. cant find any android sample.

Please help regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of any Google Play Store API specifically for the Android platform (or any platform for that matter). Google certainly does not officially have an API for that. But [Andlytics](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.andlyticsproject&hl=en), one of the most popular apps of it's kind on the Google Play Store is also an Open Source application.

It is available on github here: [Andlytics](https://github.com/AndlyticsProject/andlytics). This should be helpful getting you started. I think it works on scrapping data. Mere speculation on my part about this of course.

**UPDATE:**

> A re-look to the link by the OP reveals that the library is already in
>   Java.
>
> A quote from the webpage:
>   https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/ This is not an official
>   api. I'm not afiliated to google in any way.
>
> This library allow you to ask directly google's official android
>   market servers for information, search for apps, ...
>
> Main target is java but it can be easily adapted to other languages
>   since it's Google ProtoBuf based.
>
> There is a Ruby port by jberkel here and a PHP port by splitfeed here.
>   These is also a crawler on top of this library by Raunak Gupta here.

And this is a link to it's source: https://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FAndroidMarketApi%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgc%2Fandroid%2Fmarket%2Fapi

Perhaps, it can be, somehow, used in an Android app too.

Hope it helps. ;-)