# Android purchase date of application

Tags: android

Is it possible to check what date the app was actually purchased, Not the in-app purchases, the actual date the user purchased the original application from the google store.  I have found things like packageInfo.firstInstallTime, but that changes if you clear the device and reinstall etc.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is on-topic, but the only way to store data across installations is to persist it somewhere (like a server). You would have to get the gmail account associated with the purchase, associate a purchase ID and then check purchase date.

This is flawed because a re-install on a new device would look the same as a re-install on an existing device. It's also possible for a user to have two devices with the same gmail account, and therefore two (or more) active, valid installs and a single purchase. Most, but not all devices have a unique device ID.

And while there is no Official Google Play API (to request the data from Google), here is a good link for unofficial/creative options for search and content, but nothing for transaction data (which would probably lead to security risks without an official API):

[how to get information of google play store in my android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14643597/how-to-get-information-of-google-play-store-in-my-android-application)

Comment: Yer, trouble is we dont have access to a server to store the information on, i wish we did as it would allow for alot of other things to be sorted easier :D

Comment: see my edit - I haven't seen a market API for what you are wanting (assuming you want the app to query Google Play to get this data, which is the only other way to do this)